# Invoke a WebRequest using Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

Am new to scripting. Am stuck with some errors when i try to hit a web service with the input being a xml.

Got the content of the xml and when i try to invoke the WebRequest.

```
[xml]$sun= Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -CalculateTax post -ContentType "String" -InFile $Input.OuterXml.
```

where, $uri is the variable which has the url of the service
CalculateTax is the Method of the Service
$Input is the Variable which has the XML content 
Getting the error as

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CalculateTax'.   
+    [xml]$sun= Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -CalculateTax Post -ContentType "string"  ...
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is no `-CalculateTax` parameter in `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. And, that is the error you see.

```
PS C:\> Get-Command Invoke-WebRequest -Syntax

Invoke-WebRequest [-Uri] <uri> [-UseBasicParsing] [-WebSession <WebRequestSession>] [-SessionVariable <string>]
[-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseDefaultCredentials] [-CertificateThumbprint <string>] [-Certificate
<X509Certificate>] [-UserAgent <string>] [-DisableKeepAlive] [-TimeoutSec <int>] [-Headers <IDictionary>]
[-MaximumRedirection <int>] [-Method <WebRequestMethod>] [-Proxy <uri>] [-ProxyCredential <pscredential>]
[-ProxyUseDefaultCredentials] [-Body <Object>] [-ContentType <string>] [-TransferEncoding <string>] [-InFile <string>]
[-OutFile <string>] [-PassThru] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Instead of using `Invoke-WebRequest`, if you are looking at calling a specific method, Look at `New-WebServiceProxy`. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
PS C:\>$URI = "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL"
PS C:\>$zip = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -Namespace WebServiceProxy -Class USZip
PS C:\>$zip | get-member -type method
PS C:\>$zip.getinfobyzip(20500).table
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I have used New-WebServiceProxy. And it created the proxy for CalculateTax method.